# Is it possible to create json keys as typescript objects?

Tags: typescript

Is is possible to create a Typescript interface for the following JSON where the keys of the JSON object change?

I am having a hard time defining a changing key (`userFilter`, `activityFilter` in my example) as a field name in the typescript definition

```json
 {
  "userFilter": {
    "label": "Users",
    "options": [{
        "label": "Admin",
        "value": "ADMIN"
      },
      {
        "label": "Viewer",
        "value": "VIEWER"
      }
    ]
  },
   "activityFilter": {
     "label": "Activity",
     "options": [{
         "label": "Active",
         "value": "ACTIVE"
       },
       {
         "label": "Inactive",
         "value": "INACTIVE"
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could try something like:

```
interface optionsType {label:string, value:string}

interface test {
    [key:string]:{
        label:string,
        options:optionsType[]
    }
}
```